# Nativescript build error after updating to 2.5.4

Tags: nativescript

I updated NS to the current patch and suddenly I'm getting the error `30276 bus error tns build ios` when ever I try to build. Below are the things I have tried in order to fix the issue, none of which worked. Anyone have an idea what's going on?

- Add/Remove platforms
- Roll back to the last version of NS which worked (2.5.3)
- Updated core modules
- Completed deleted and reinstalled node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a `"nativescript":"2.5.4"` parameter getting added to the dependencies in the package.json after updating Nativecsript. Removing this dependency fixed the issue.